# how to remove NaN from the large dataset

Tags: python, pandas

When I am tring to plot the cluster , I am getting an error of "ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
complete_dataset = pd.read_csv("311_Call_Center_Service_Requests.csv")
data = complete_dataset[['X','Y']]
plt.scatter(data['X'],data['Y'],s=30)
plt.show()
Kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 6, init= 'k=means++', max_iter = 300, n_init = 10,random_state =1)
Kmeans.fit(data)
print(Kmeans.labels_)
```

this code is working fine but not able to remove NaN from my dataset. while using, complete_dataset = complete_dataset.dropna() i get the error< ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 2)) while a minimum of 1 is required.> what should i do? thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `dropna()`:

```
complete_dataset.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Or assign :

```
complete_dataset = complete_dataset.dropna()
```

Comment: while using, complete_dataset = complete_dataset.dropna() i get the error< ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 2)) while a minimum of 1 is required.> what should i do? thank you for helping me.